# std::vector<char> into std::vector<T> conversion c++

Tags: c++

I want to create a `std::vector<T>` of length `len` from serialized data contained in a `std::vector<char>` of length `len * (sizeof T)`, without copying data when not necessary (it may not be possible for, e.g., align requirements of `T`).
In other words I look for an optimization of the following code, operating on the same guarantees:

```
template<typename T>
auto copyStuff(std::vector<char>&&input) {
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.resize(input.size()/(sizeof T));
    for (int i=0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        memcpy(&result[i], &input[i * (sizeof T)], sizeof T);
    }
    return result;
}
```

which

- avoids copying at all when possible
- otherwise copies all bytes in a single `memcpy` call if possible
- or falls back to the above implementation or equivalent when neither is possible.

Is there a standard way, or a portable library, to achieve this (or a "good enough" approximation)?

Clarifications:

- I need to be able to only assume that `T` is trivially copiable, and the layout of the input `std::vector<char>` is simply the concatenation of the memory representation of the item which I want to construct.
- I am looking for a way to be certain that I'm not going into undefined or implementation defined behaviour when doing optimizations
- I am willing to consider non-standard container libraries (instead of `vector`s) if they offer this low overhead type punning.

Comment: How are you getting this data?  If you are using something like `read` you can just do `std::vector<T> data(size_needed); stream.read(static_cast<char *>(data.data()), size_needed * sizeof(T));`

Comment: @NathanOliver I am writing a library which can make no assumption on the origin of the data, other than what can be inferred by the type system (e.g. the allocator used for the vector)

Comment: Please take a bit of time to explain why the question is "unclear" and need to be closed, do not just flag and run without commenting. I tried my best to explain the situation and I believe what you are doing is very rude.

Comment: the question would already be a little more clear if you added your previous comment to the question (not my votes btw)

Comment: @user463035818 I was planning on clarifying that (and already moving on that direction while you were writing). Downvotes are personal opinion on whether a question is uninteresting and that's ok even without an explanation, but for close votes it is more constructive to add a comment on what's wrong. I begin to suspect that people flag and try to close question they can't answer in an effort to draw attention to the question they answered in the hope to get some upvotes. Or I have enemies which close vote everything I post (this has happened to me other times).

Comment: @NathanOliver your idea is worth considering though, that is instead of propagating `vector<char>` I can use streams to encapsulate lazy evaluation of the data source (and directly read them as `int` when I need them into an array). That might not be feasible for my particular setup but it's still a strategy that a reader might deem interesting. Would you elaborate that in an answer (or I can do it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to get vector of one type from another type without copying.

You can avoid one set of copies by constructing the vector of `T` (of sufficient size) initially, and then writing the serialized data directly onto that vector without the use of an intermediate vector of chars.

A few caveats:

- Copying the data directly will mean that the data is not portable to CPU's with different endianness or otherwise different representation of numbers, so this form of serialisation is not appropriate for communication across systems (such as networking, shared files).
- `T` must be trivially copyable type.

Comment: Caveats are covered by the assumption that the example low-performance code which copies every single element is working. Is it always true that the vector buffer binary representation is the same as the binary representations of the single element binary representation simply chained together (i.e., the vector buffer can be `memcpy`ed as whole if the single elements are trivially copiable)?

Comment: @pqnet Yes. An array is trivially copyable if the elements are.

Comment: That's the first part I was unaware of